# Git ignore all files of a certain type except in all subdirectories of a certain directory?

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm trying to make a gitignore file that will ignore all .jar files unless they're in a folder called libs. Here's my basic file structure:

```
-.gitignore 
-libs/
    -goodFile.jar
    -someFolder/
        -subFolder/
            -alsoGood.jar
-otherCode/
    -fileToExclude.jar
-otherOtherCode/
    -otherSubfolder/
        -alsoExclude.jar
```

Currently in .gitignore I've tried:

```
*.jar
!libs
!libs/
!libs/*
!libs/**
!libs/**/
!libs/**/*.jar
!libs/*.jar
```

Either on their own, in combination, or even all together. None of them work. The only way I've found to do it is to either put in another .gitignore file into `libs/` (which I would prefer to avoid) or use a `!libs/*/*/*.jar` line for every possible level of subdirectory. Is there a way to make it ignore all jars except the ones in libs?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

How about:

```
*.jar
!libs/**/*.jar
```

The order is important.

**Edit**
I used your project structure and have the following output after I did a `git add` and `git status`

```
$ git stat
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   .gitignore
    new file:   libs/goodFile.jar
    new file:   libs/someFolder/subFolder/alsoGood.jar
    new file:   libs/someFolder/subFolder/test/anotherFolder/test.jar



$ cat .gitignore 
*.jar
!libs/**/*.jar
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it still ignores any .jars that aren't in libs/ directly and are instead in subfolders.

Comment: are you sure. I just tried it with your suggested structure and it works perfectly

Comment: Okay, it'll pick it up if it's one subdirectory down, but most of the jars I need to include are 4 or 5 levels deep. Those ones aren't being picked up.

Comment: It still works with nested subfolders (updated the answer). What git version are you using? I have 1.8.5.2

Comment: git version 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)

Comment: have you removed the rest of your relate git ignore lines.. you just need these two...

Comment: I just created a brand new project using the layout, same problem. Git ignore is just those 2 lines. This may be a different issue.

Comment: Check also your `.git/info/exclude`  file for possible hidden excludes.

Comment: Nope, nothing there except the standard comments.

Comment: This worked. Turns out the issue was my git version. I was running 1.7 and support for "**" was only added in 1.8.