# How to git ignore all files and subdirectories from a certain directory except with some exceptions?

Tags: git

I am trying to ignore all files and subdirectories from the directory `.config` that is located at the root of the repository except the file `.config/vimb/config` and the subdirectory `.config/ranger/`.

This is my `.gitconfig`:

```
# Ignore the contents of .config
.config/*
 
# Avoid Blocking
!.config/
!.config/vimb
!.config/vimb/config
!.config/ranger/
```

As a result git seems to ignore the entire directory event the files and subdirectories that are maked with the `!` wildcard.

For a record I also tried the following:

```
# Ignore Everything
*

# Add files
!somefile1
!somefile2

# Ignore Config
.config/*
 
# Avoid Blocking 
!.config/
!.config/vimb
!.config/vimb/config
!.config/ranger/
```

Also, I attempted ignoring everything and using `!` to add each individual file and directory to be staged.

As of now, I used the following sources to resolve the issue:

- [Git ignore all files of a certain type except in all subdirectories of a certain directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537528/git-ignore-all-files-of-a-certain-type-except-in-all-subdirectories-of-a-certain)
- [Make .gitignore ignore everything except a few files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987142/make-gitignore-ignore-everything-except-a-few-files)
- [How to .gitignore everything except a few files](https://medium.com/@lynzt/how-to-gitignore-everything-except-a-few-files-6a8f392e1674)

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The docs seem to cover this situation quite well: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is The solution that I came up with. To sum up, my objective was to exclude all files and subdirectories from `.config` directory except the `.config/ranger` directory with all files and directories in it and the `.config/vimb/config` configuration file. The following `.gitignore` code did the job.

```
# Block 
.config/**

# Avoid Blocking 
!.config/
!.config/**/
!.config/vimb/config
!.config/ranger/
!.config/ranger/**
!.config/ranger/**/
!.config/ranger/init.rc
```

`git status` command outputs the following as expected:

```
    new file:   .config/ranger/commands.py                                                                         │
    new file:   .config/ranger/rc.conf                                                                             │
    new file:   .config/vimb/config                                                                                │
    new file:   .gitignore
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you can check at any point why a file is still ignored with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- path/to/file
```

Second, You need to ignore files only, and exclude *folders* from your ignore rule, if you want then to be able to exclude files in them:

```
.config/**
!.config/**/
!.config/vimb/config/**
!.config/ranger/**
```

This is because:

[**It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21643672/6309)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it put me on the right track.

Comment: @unknown Great! What solution did you find?